# Triangulation & Direct linear transform

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, linear-algebra

Following Hartley/Zisserman's Multiview Geometery, Algorithm 12: The optimal triangulation method (p318), I got the corresponding image points xhat1 and xhat2 (step 10). In step 11, one needs to compute the 3D point Xhat. One such method is Direct Linear Transform (DLT), mentioned in 12.2 (p312) and 4.1 (p88).

The homogenous method (DLT), p312-313, states that it finds a solution as the unit singular vector corresponding to the smallest singular value of A, thus,

```
A = [xhat1(1) * P1(3,:)' - P1(1,:)' ;
      xhat1(2) * P1(3,:)' - P1(2,:)' ;
      xhat2(1) * P2(3,:)' - P2(1,:)' ;
      xhat2(2) * P2(3,:)' - P2(2,:)' ];

[Ua Ea Va] = svd(A);
Xhat = Va(:,end);

plot3(Xhat(1),Xhat(2),Xhat(3), 'r.');
```

However, A is a 16x1 matrix, resulting in a Va that is 1x1.

What am I doing wrong (and a fix) in getting the 3D point?

For what its worth sample data:

```
xhat1 =

  1.0e+009 *

    4.9973
   -0.2024
    0.0027


xhat2 =

  1.0e+011 *

    2.0729
    2.6624
    0.0098


P1 =

  699.6674         0  392.1170         0
         0  701.6136  304.0275         0
         0         0    1.0000         0


P2 =

  1.0e+003 *

   -0.7845    0.0508   -0.1592    1.8619
   -0.1379    0.7338    0.1649    0.6825
   -0.0006    0.0001    0.0008    0.0010


A =    <- my computation

  1.0e+011 *

   -0.0000
         0
    0.0500
         0
         0
   -0.0000
   -0.0020
         0
   -1.3369
    0.2563
    1.5634
    2.0729
   -1.7170
    0.3292
    2.0079
    2.6624
```

**Update** Working code for section xi in algorithm

```
% xi
A = [xhat1(1) * P1(3,:) - P1(1,:) ;
     xhat1(2) * P1(3,:) - P1(2,:) ;
     xhat2(1) * P2(3,:) - P2(1,:) ;
     xhat2(2) * P2(3,:) - P2(2,:) ];

A(1,:) = A(1,:)/norm(A(1,:));
A(2,:) = A(2,:)/norm(A(2,:));
A(3,:) = A(3,:)/norm(A(3,:));
A(4,:) = A(4,:)/norm(A(4,:));

[Ua Ea Va] = svd(A);
X = Va(:,end);
X = X / X(4);   % 3D Point
```

Comment: It might be better to post with the smallest expected inputs for xhat1, P1 etc so we can copy and paste a working example and do not have to assume what form your inputs are in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As is mentioned in the book (sec 12.2), **p**<sup>i **T**</sup> are the **rows** of **P**. Therefore, you don't need to transpose `P1(k,:)` (i.e. the right formulation is `A = [xhat1(1) * P1(3,:) - P1(1,:) ; ...`).

I hope that was just a typo.

Additionally, it is recommended to normalize each row of `A` with its L2 norm, i.e. for all `i`

`A(i,:) = A(i,:)/norm(A(i,:));`

And if you want to plot the triangulated 3D points, you have to normalize `Xhat` before plotting (its meaningless otherwise), i.e.

`Xhat = Xhat/Xhat(4);`

Comment: Jacob, you mention that the rows of A should be normalized. Is the Frobenius norm(?) much different than the normalization on p109 which normalizes xhat1 and xhat2, performs the DLT then de-normalizes?

Comment: No, it's different - it's just used to make the SVD computation utilize the cosine measure. And I meant the L2 norm, i.e. ||A(i,:)||.

Comment: In my case, the normalization of rows of A before applying SVD resulted in unpredictable reprojection errors (calculated by projecting the triangulated point onto the cameras and calculating the distance between the projections and the inputs for triangulation) ranging from 0.007 to 22px. Removing the normalization brought the range to 0.001-0.4px.

Answer (score 1):

```
A(1,:) = A(1,:)/norm(A(1,:));
A(2,:) = A(2,:)/norm(A(2,:));
A(3,:) = A(3,:)/norm(A(3,:));
A(4,:) = A(4,:)/norm(A(4,:));
```

Could be simplified as `A = normr(A)`.