# Triangulation using the direct linear transform taken directly from Hartley & Zisserman

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, triangulation

Below is a Matlab function that implements the triangulation method as described in Multiple View Geometry. It takes the 8 corner points of a cube (OriginalPoints) and projects them on two screens. The screen points are then in CameraPoints and ProjectorPoints. The goal is to reconstruct the original points from these two views using the Direct Linear Transform. Unfortunately the result is gibberish.

There is [another topic here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276445/triangulation-direct-linear-transform), from which the normalization of the rows of A are taken, but that did not improve the result.

Three general questions:

- When normalizing the data before the SVD (origin = centroid and avg distance = sqrt(2)), do I calculate the average distance over (x,y) or (x, y, w)? Inhomogeneous or homogeneous?
- After every operation, where possible, I scale the homogeneous coordinate w back to 1.0, is this correct?
- Since the camera matrices are known completely (not just up to a projective transformation) the resulting points should differ no more from the original points than a Euclidean transformation, right?

```
    % Demos the triangulation method using the direct linear transform
    % algorithm
    function testTriangulation()
        close all;

    camWidth = 800;
    camHeight = 600;
    projectorWidth = 5080;
    projectorHeight = 760;

    % camera matrices
    CameraMatrix =    [
                    -1.81066 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000;
                    0.00000 2.41421 0.00000 0.00000;
                    0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.50000
                ];

    ProjectorMatrix =   [
                    -0.36118 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
                    0.00000 2.00875 1.33916 0.00000
                    0.00000 -0.55470 0.83205 1.80278
                ];

    % generating original points and displaying them
    OriginalPoints =    [
                            -0.2 -0.2 -0.2 -0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2;
                            -0.2 -0.2 0.2 0.2 -0.2 -0.2 0.2 0.2;
                            -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2;
                            1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
                        ];    
    scatter3(OriginalPoints(1, :), OriginalPoints(2, :), OriginalPoints(3,:));
    title('Original Points');

    % projecting and normalizing camera points
    CameraPoints = CameraMatrix * OriginalPoints;
    for i = 1:3
        CameraPoints(i, :) = CameraPoints(i, :) ./ CameraPoints(3,:);
    end
    %     figure();
    %     scatter(CameraPoints(1,:), CameraPoints(2,:));
    %     title('Projected Camera Points');

    % transforming camera points to screen coordinates
    camXOffset = camWidth / 2;
    camYOffset = camHeight / 2; 
    CameraPoints(1,:) = CameraPoints(1,:) * camXOffset + camXOffset;
    CameraPoints(2,:) = CameraPoints(2,:) * camYOffset + camYOffset;
    figure();
    scatter(CameraPoints(1,:), CameraPoints(2,:));
    title('Projected Camera Points in Screen Coordinates');


    % projecting and normalizing projector points
    ProjectorPoints = ProjectorMatrix * OriginalPoints;
    for i = 1:3
        ProjectorPoints(i, :) = ProjectorPoints(i, :) ./ ProjectorPoints(3,:);
    end
    %     figure();
    %     scatter(ProjectorPoints(1,:), ProjectorPoints(2,:));
    %     title('Projected Projector Points');

    % transforming projector points to screen coordinates
    projectorXOffset = projectorWidth / 2;
    projectorYOffset = projectorHeight / 2; 
    ProjectorPoints(1,:) = ProjectorPoints(1,:) * projectorXOffset + projectorXOffset;
    ProjectorPoints(2,:) = ProjectorPoints(2,:) * projectorYOffset + projectorYOffset;
    figure();
    scatter(ProjectorPoints(1,:), ProjectorPoints(2,:));
    title('Projected Projector Points in Screen Coordinates');


    % normalizing camera points (i.e. origin is
    % the centroid and average distance is sqrt(2)).
    camCenter = mean(CameraPoints, 2);
    CameraPoints(1,:) =  CameraPoints(1,:) - camCenter(1);
    CameraPoints(2,:) = CameraPoints(2,:) - camCenter(2);
    avgDistance = 0.0;
    for i = 1:length(CameraPoints(1,:))
        avgDistance = avgDistance + norm(CameraPoints(:, i));
    end
    avgDistance = avgDistance / length(CameraPoints(1, :));
    scaleFactor = sqrt(2) / avgDistance;
    CameraPoints(1:2, :) = CameraPoints(1:2, :) * scaleFactor;

    % normalizing projector points (i.e. origin is
    % the centroid and average distance is sqrt(2)).
    projectorCenter = mean(ProjectorPoints, 2);
    ProjectorPoints(1,:) =  ProjectorPoints(1,:) - projectorCenter(1);
    ProjectorPoints(2,:) = ProjectorPoints(2,:) - projectorCenter(2);
    avgDistance = 0.0;
    for i = 1:length(ProjectorPoints(1,:))
        avgDistance = avgDistance + norm(ProjectorPoints(:, i));
    end
    avgDistance = avgDistance / length(ProjectorPoints(1, :));
    scaleFactor = sqrt(2) / avgDistance;
    ProjectorPoints(1:2, :) = ProjectorPoints(1:2, :) * scaleFactor;


    % triangulating points
    TriangulatedPoints = zeros(size(OriginalPoints));
    for i = 1:length(OriginalPoints(1, :))
        A = [
                CameraPoints(1, i) * CameraMatrix(3, :) - CameraMatrix(1, :);
                CameraPoints(2, i) * CameraMatrix(3, :) - CameraMatrix(2, :);
                ProjectorPoints(1, i) * ProjectorMatrix(3,:) - ProjectorMatrix(1,:);
                ProjectorPoints(2, i) * ProjectorMatrix(3,:) - ProjectorMatrix(2,:)
            ];

        % normalizing rows of A, as suggested in a topic on StackOverflow
        A(1,:) = A(1,:)/norm(A(1,:));
        A(2,:) = A(2,:)/norm(A(2,:));
        A(3,:) = A(3,:)/norm(A(3,:));
        A(4,:) = A(4,:)/norm(A(4,:));

        [U S V] = svd(A);
        TriangulatedPoints(:, i) = V(:, end);
    end
    for i = 1:4
        TriangulatedPoints(i, :) = TriangulatedPoints(i, :) ./ TriangulatedPoints(4, :);
    end
    figure()
    scatter3(TriangulatedPoints(1, :), TriangulatedPoints(2, :), TriangulatedPoints(3, :));
    title('Triangulated Points');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was missing from the code above, was that the camera matrices also need to be transformed by the normalizing transformation. Below is an example that works. Notice also the difference in structure of the normalizing transformations. In the question's example the scaling factor is put in the last element. Below it's multiplied with all the elements, such that the last element is 1.

```
function testTriangulationDavid()
  close all
  clear all

  P = [
      -1.81066 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000;
      0.00000 2.41421 0.00000 0.00000;
      0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 1.50000
      ];

  Q =  [
      -0.36118 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
      0.00000 2.00875 1.33916 0.00000
      0.00000 -0.55470 0.83205 1.80278
      ];


  % homogenous 3D coordinates
  Pts =  [
          -0.2 -0.2 -0.2 -0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2;
          -0.2 -0.2 0.2 0.2 -0.2 -0.2 0.2 0.2;
          -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2 -0.2 0.2;
          1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
      ];    

  numPts = length(Pts(1,:));

  % project points
  PPtsHom = P*Pts;
  QPtsHom = Q*Pts;

  % normalize for homogenous scaling
  for i = 1:3
      PPtsHom(i, :) = PPtsHom(i, :) ./ PPtsHom(3, :);
      QPtsHom(i, :) = QPtsHom(i, :) ./ QPtsHom(3, :);
  end

  % 2D cartesian coordinates
  PPtsCart = PPtsHom(1:2,:);
  QPtsCart = QPtsHom(1:2,:);



  % compute normalizing transform

  % calc centroid
  centroidPPtsCart = mean(PPtsCart,2);
  centroidQPtsCart = mean(QPtsCart,2);

  % calc mean distance to centroid
  normsPPtsCart = zeros(1, numPts);
  normsQPtsCart = zeros(1, numPts);
  for i = 1:numPts
    normsPPtsCart(1,i) = norm(PPtsCart(:,i) - centroidPPtsCart);
    normsQPtsCart(1,i) = norm(QPtsCart(:,i) - centroidQPtsCart);
  end
  mdcPPtsCart = mean(normsPPtsCart);
  mdcQPtsCart = mean(normsQPtsCart);

  % setup transformation
  scaleP = sqrt(2)/mdcPPtsCart;
  scaleQ = sqrt(2)/mdcQPtsCart;

  tP = [ scaleP 0      -scaleP*centroidPPtsCart(1);
    0      scaleP -scaleP*centroidPPtsCart(2);
    0      0      1];
  tQ = [ scaleQ 0      -scaleQ*centroidQPtsCart(1);
    0      scaleQ -scaleQ*centroidQPtsCart(2);
    0      0      1];


  % transform points
  PPtsHom = tP * PPtsHom;
  QPtsHom = tQ * QPtsHom;

  % normalize for homogenous scaling
  for i = 1:3
      PPtsHom(i, :) = PPtsHom(i, :) ./ PPtsHom(3, :);
      QPtsHom(i, :) = QPtsHom(i, :) ./ QPtsHom(3, :);
  end
  % 2D cartesian coordinates
  PPtsCart = PPtsHom(1:2,:);
  QPtsCart = QPtsHom(1:2,:);

  % transform cameras
  P = tP * P;
  Q = tQ * Q;


  % triangulating points
  TriangulatedPoints = zeros(4,numPts);
  for i = 1:numPts
      A = [
          PPtsCart(1, i) * P(3, :) - P(1, :);
          PPtsCart(2, i) * P(3, :) - P(2, :);
          QPtsCart(1, i) * Q(3,:) - Q(1,:);
          QPtsCart(2, i) * Q(3,:) - Q(2,:)
      ]
      return;

      [U S V] = svd(A);
      TriangulatedPoints(:, i) = V(:, end);
  end
  for i = 1:4
      TriangulatedPoints(i, :) = TriangulatedPoints(i, :) ./ TriangulatedPoints(4, :);
  end
  figure()
  scatter3(TriangulatedPoints(1, :), TriangulatedPoints(2, :), TriangulatedPoints(3, :));
  title('Triangulated Points');
  axis equal;
```